# How do I update MongoDB gpg keys on Debian Linux bullseye 11?

Tags: updates, apt-get, mongodb, debian-bullseye

OS: Debian 11 bullseye
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.0-26-cloud-amd64

I did:

```
apt-get update
```

and got:

```
Err:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
    Fetched 141 kB in 1s (175 kB/s)
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    All packages are up to date.
    W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
    W: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 58712A2291FA4AD5 MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to update the key list by doing:

```
sudo apt-key list | \
grep "expired: " | \
sed -ne 's|pub .*/\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|gp' | \
xargs -n1 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
```

However, it said:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

[I found the update string I tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733340/mongodb-gpg-invalid-signatures). I realize now it's for Ubuntu and this is Debian. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Hackeron, I did not.  I went back to using the Docker image on-premise that still works.  The only plan as of now is to upgrade the database version itself at some point.